# how can i delay the random choice repeatedly?

Tags: python, random, repeat

```
    global bullet
    global ball
    global ball_x
    pred1 = [bullet, ball]
    pred2 = random.choice(pred1)
    process = image(pred2, ball_x, 10)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

ball_x = [100, 200, 300]

I need to know how I can program the "process" to repeat itself after the "0.5" second and then sleep again for another "0.5" seconds and so on repeating this process forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put `process` in an endless loop with a 0.5 second delay, you could do something like this

```
while True:
    process = image(pred2, ball_x, 10)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

First add `import time` or `from time import sleep`. Then in a `while True:` loop do `time.sleep(0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below, it will alternate between sleeping and throwing ball then take a rest.

```
global bullet
global ball
global ball_x
pred1 = [bullet, ball]
throw = False
while true:
    pred2 = random.choice(pred1)
    if throw:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        throw = False
    else:
        process = image(pred2, ball_x, 10)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        throw = True
```

Comment: thanks .. i will :)